# Why would using SessionManager prevent HTTP metrics from being gathered by NewRelic?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, newrelic

I'm using NewRelic v6.3.0 and Alamofire v4.7.3 (latest available at time of writing). I recently switched to use Alamofire's SessionManager class so that I could also use their RequestAdapter class. Since I have made this change, NewRelic no longer reports certain metrics, specifically HTTP Requests (response times, requests per minute, etc). I have configured the SessionManager using the default options as shown here.

```
let sessionManager: SessionManager = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
        session.adapter = CustomRequestAdapter()
        return session
    }()
```

I have also tried creating a new session manager for each call. (Not ideal)
If I remove the references to sessionManager and use the original/default `Alamofire.request...` then the metrics are reported to NewRelic once more. Any thoughts?

Comment: Find out how NewRelic works and then you can find out how Alamofire may be interacting with it. My guess is NewRelic does some sort of swizzling to intercept certain URLSession APIs, so it my not play nice with Alamofire.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that NewRelic does swizzling to capture and log what it does. I'm hoping that someone from the NewRelic team will reach out, as this is the forum their site says to use for questions like this. I believe that there is a bug in their code that prevents them from allowing me to use Alamofire's SessionManager.